# How can I user a parameterFilter with a switch parameter when mocking in Pester?

Tags: powershell, pester

Using Pester, I'm mocking an advanced function which takes, amongst other parameters, a switch.  How do I create a `-parameterFilter` for the mock which includes the switch parameter?

I've tried:

```
-parameterFilter { $Domain -eq 'MyDomain' -and $Verbose -eq $true }

-parameterFilter { $Domain -eq 'MyDomain' -and $Verbose }

-parameterFilter { $Domain -eq 'MyDomain' -and $Verbose -eq 'True' }
```

to no avail.

Comment: Are you receiving an actual error message?  There are issues with mocking calls when the subject under test has been imported as a module.  Note the limitations discussed here https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/Mocking-with-Pester

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
-parameterFilter { $Domain -eq 'MyDomain' -and $Verbose.IsPresent}
```

Comment: I had to use `[System.Boolean]$Verbose.IsPresent -eq $true` to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

`-Verbose` is a common parameter, which makes this a bit more tricky.  You never actually see a `$Verbose` variable in your function, and the same applies to the parameter filter.  Instead, when someone sets the common `-Verbose` switch, what actually happens is the `$VerbosePreference` variable gets set to `Continue` instead of `SilentlyContinue`.

You can, however, find the Verbose switch in the `$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable, and you should be able to use that in your mock filter:

```
Mock someFunction -parameterFilter { $Domain -eq 'MyDomain' -and $PSBoundParameters['Verbose'] -eq $true }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to work fine:

**Test.ps1** - This just contains two functions.  Both take the same parameters but `Test-Call` calls through to `Mocked-Call`.  We will mock `Mocked-Call` in our tests.

```
Function Test-Call {
    param(
        $text,
        [switch]$switch
    )

    Mocked-Call $text -switch:$switch
}

Function Mocked-Call {
    param(
        $text,
        [switch]$switch
    )

    $text
}
```

**Test.Tests.ps1** - This is our actual test script.  Note we have two mock implementations for `Mocked-Call`.  The first will match when the `switch` parameter is set to *true*.  The second will match when the `text` parameter has a value of *fourth* **and** the `switch` parameter has a value of *false*.

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$sut = (Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).Replace(".Tests.", ".")
. "$here\$sut"

Describe "Test-Call" {

    It "mocks switch parms" {
        Mock Mocked-Call { "mocked" } -parameterFilter { $switch -eq $true }
        Mock Mocked-Call { "mocked again" } -parameterFilter { $text -eq "fourth" -and $switch -eq $false }

        $first = Test-Call "first" 
        $first | Should Be "first"

        $second = Test-Call "second" -switch
        $second | Should Be "mocked"

        $third = Test-Call "third" -switch:$true
        $third | Should Be "mocked"

        $fourth = Test-Call "fourth" -switch:$false
        $fourth | Should Be "mocked again"

    }
}
```

Running the tests shows green:

```
Describing Test-Call
[+]   mocks switch parms 17ms
Tests completed in 17ms
Passed: 1 Failed: 0
```